# XML data will not go into child element

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am just starting to learn about XMLHttpRequest and getting data from XML file in javascript, so I have been fiddling around with this code (from the [W3C site, on displaying XML data](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp)), and ended up with this:

```
<style>
div[ui="note"] {
border: 1px solid #999;
color: red;
}

</style>
</head>


<div ui="panel-area">
    <div ui="panel">

        <div ui="note">
            <strong>Content should be here</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
document.querySelector('div[ui="panel"]').innerHTML += "<div ui='note'><strong>Content should be here</strong>";
document.querySelector('div[ui="panel"]').innerHTML += x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
document.querySelector('div[ui="panel"]').innerHTML +="</div>";
</script>
</body>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
</CD>
<CD>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
</CD>
 <!-- Lots more names -->
</CATALOG>
```

This will create a `<div ui="note">` with an artist name *underneath* it, but the problem is, that I cannot get it to go inside of the `<div ui="note">`:

[This is the image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plrzG.jpg)

Is there any way to get the content into the note div (no tables please) - that does not depend on special one-browser features, and will work on mobile safari?

Comment: you should avoid synchronous xmlhttprequests - as of firefox 30 they are considered deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `.innerHTML += ...` to concatenate incomplete pieces of html to your `'div[ui="panel"]'` element.

On the first line you add this:

```
"<div ui='note'><strong>Content should be here</strong>"
```

but the browser doesn't know that a few lines later you will be adding the closing `"</div>"` tag so it doesn't know that you want to put your artist name strings inside that div.

(Also, even if that did work, your loop creates multiple new opening `<div>` tags but only adds one closing `</div>` after the loop.)

Try creating complete html and then add it to the panel div in one step:

```
var newHTML = "";
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
   newHTML += "<div ui='note'><strong>Content should be here</strong>"
            + x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            + "</div>";
}
document.querySelector('div[ui="panel"]').innerHTML += newHTML;
```

If it is your intention for each artist name to appear where you have the hardcoded "Content should be here" string then try this:

```
var newHTML = "";
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
   newHTML += "<div ui='note'><strong>"
            + x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            + "</strong></div>";
}
document.querySelector('div[ui="panel"]').innerHTML += newHTML;
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that you are doing an ajax request, or that your source data is in xml format. It's just the way you were putting those values together as not-quite-valid html.